# Internal properties are not handled by NSubstitute

Tags: c#, internal, nsubstitute

Suppose, that I've got a following class:

```
public abstract class Test
{
    internal abstract int Prop 
    {
        get;
    }
}
```

Now, I try to make a mock using NSubstitute:

```
var mock = Substitute.For<Test>();
```

But that fails:

> Method 'get_Prop' in type 'Castle.Proxies.TestProxy' from assembly 
>   'DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
>   PublicKeyToken=a621a9e7e5c32e69' does not have an implementation.

I thought of adding `NSubstitute` to `[InternalsVisibleTo]`, but unfortunately my tested assembly is signed, `NSubstitute` is not and `Internals` cannot be `VisibleTo` unsigned class.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found the solution. One has to add the following line to the `Assembly.cs` file of the assembly, *he wants to test* (*not* the test assembly):

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]
```

Comment: Which public key are you using there? Is it a constant?

Comment: It was some time ago, but AFAIR this is a public key extracted from NSubstitute assemblies (there's a way to do this with tools available with Visual Studio).

Comment: Yeah it appears to be constant. I pasted this into my assemblyinfo.cs and it worked as is.

Comment: Use [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo(InternalsVisible.ToDynamicProxyGenAssembly2)] instead

Comment: @Austin Salgat  I think you meant [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]

Comment: Edited to account for no need for the public key.

Comment: @ArialdoMartini The Castle.Core assembly has a class InternalsVisible under the Castle.Core.Internal namespace meant for this specific use. The documentation states:

`// Constant to use when making assembly internals visible to proxy types generated by DynamicProxy. Required when proxying internal types. [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo(CoreInternalsVisible.ToDynamicProxyGenAssembly2)]`

Answer (score 1):

The voted answer does not work anymore.

Use the following instead.
Either add this to any `.cs` file in your project:

```cs
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]
```

or this, to the `.csproj` file of the Project:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <AssemblyAttribute Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo">
        <_Parameter1>DynamicProxyGenAssembly2</_Parameter1>
    </AssemblyAttribute>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the internals of the other assembly visible to the proxy generation library being used by NSubstitute "under the hood" called DynamicProxyGenAssembly2. This is how you can easily do it in NetCore+.

Example in the .csproj of the project with the interface you're looking to mock:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <!-- Required for Test project to test internal classes/interfaces -->
    <InternalsVisibleTo Include="YourProject.Tests" />
    <!-- Required for NSubstitute to mock internal classes/interfaces -->
    <InternalsVisibleTo Include="DynamicProxyGenAssembly2" />
</ItemGroup>
```