# Cannot unit test a class with a method returning RedisResult with StackExchange.Redis

Tags: c#, stackexchange.redis, nsubstitute

I have a simple wrapper for stackexchange redis:

```
public interface IRedisClient
{        
    Task<RedisResult> ScriptEvaluate(LuaScript script, object parameters);
}
```

I have a method that calls `ScriptEvaluate`

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly IRedisClient _client;

    public Foo(IRedisClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public void RunScript()
    {
        _client.ScriptEvaluate(LuaScript.Prepare(""), new object());
    }
}
```

Now when I use `NSubstitute` to mock `IRedisClient` that is injected to `Foo` and then call `RunScript`

```
public void Test()
{
    _foo = new Foo(Substitute.For<IRedisClient>());
    _foo.RunScript();
}
```

I get the following error:

> System.TypeLoadException: Method 'AsBoolean' in type
>   'Castle.Proxies.RedisResultProxy' from assembly
>   'DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=a621a9e7e5c32e69' does not have an implementation.

As far as I can see `Nsubstitute`/`Castle` internals do not manage to work with `RedisResult` properly. I did not manage to find out any workarounds.

Is it possible to do something with this?

P.S. I get the same error when I try to configure the mock to return a value (same exception):

```
_client
    .ScriptEvaluate(null, null)
    .ReturnsForAnyArgs(RedisResult.Create((RedisKey)"result"));
```

Comment: So why not mock `RedisResult`

Comment: Not sure what you mean? It seems it does not matter if I mock or not, when the substitute is created and uses the method it will always use RedisResult on it's own because that's what method returns (regardless of what I setup for the return)

Comment: This is a `NSubstitute` issue as I was able to exercise the test to completion with MOQ

Comment: Strange, does not NSubstitute use the same castle proxy as Moq?

Comment: Yes it does. So it has to be something with NSub's implementation.

Comment: Any ideas for workaround here?

Comment: I am still evaluating that.

Comment: I am convinced this is a bug with nsubstitute. If using an actual implementation of `RedisResult` the mocking library should have no reason to even evaluate it.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, I did not find any way around it and just using my own implementation :( I should probably post it on NSubstitute github. I guess Moq will actually fail as well if it will need to evaluate this class

Comment: I have raised this as [NSub issue 615](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues/615). Thank you IlyaChernomordik and @Nkosi for the helpful repro cases. If you have any more info please add it to the issue (current platform/env/package versions would be good to know). Thanks again!

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this on dotnetcore3.1 on Mac. Please let me know which platform/env/package versions you are using.

Comment: I have commented on github issue with more details @DavidTchepak, thanks for posting it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was curious about why mocking the abstract `RedisResult` was not a simple solution.

This appears to be an issue with NSubstitute's implementation.

Using the following to try and recreate the problem

```
public class Foo {
    private readonly IRedisClient _client;

    public Foo(IRedisClient client) {
        _client = client;
    }

    public Task<RedisResult> RunScript() {
        return _client.ScriptEvaluate(LuaScript.Prepare(""), new object());
    }
}
```

I was able to reproduce it using `NSubstitute` but was able to exercise the test to completion when using another mocking framework (MOQ)

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass {
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Test1() {
        //Arrange
        var expected = RedisResult.Create((RedisKey)"result");
        var _client = Substitute.For<IRedisClient>();

        _client
            .ScriptEvaluate(Arg.Any<LuaScript>(), Arg.Any<object>())
            .Returns(expected);

        var _foo = new Foo(_client);

        //Act
        var actual = await _foo.RunScript();

        //Assert
        actual.Should().Be(expected);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Test2() {
        //Arrange
        var expected = RedisResult.Create((RedisKey)"result");
        var _client = Mock.Of<IRedisClient>(_ => _.ScriptEvaluate(It.IsAny<LuaScript>(), It.IsAny<object>()) == Task.FromResult(expected));

        var _foo = new Foo(_client);

        //Act
        var actual = await _foo.RunScript();

        //Assert
        actual.Should().Be(expected);
    }
}
```

Comment: Added this example to https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues/615. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`RedisResult` is an `abstract` type, but there are `static Create` methods for common scenarios, and a few static properties such as `EmptyArray`, `NullArray`, etc. I can't tell you how to configure your particular faking layer, but ultimately, I'd expect something involving `RedisResult.Create`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have actually done that: RedisResult.Create, but it does not seem to help, I get the same error when I do configure substitute, I'll update the question shortly

Comment: I have updated the question. It seems to me that being abstract class is not the issue here but perhaps the fact that there are a number of `abstract internal` methods (`AsBoolean` from my exception being one of them). My guess is that Castle proxy creates a dynamic implementation of RedisResult but it does not "see" the internal ones, and then when this type is being used the runtime figures out not everything is implemented

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik that's a very good hypothesis. Could you try [`InternalsVisibleTo`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19974248/906)? It might also be worth trying to use `Configure` when stubbing this; `_client.Configure().ScriptEvaluate(null, null).ReturnsForAnyArgs(...)`.

Comment: I am not sure how can I use InternalsVisibleTo, I would have to compile the library from source with this attribute I assume? In the other stackoverflow post it was owned class, while my classes are in the library...